# Can't do Oauth on iOS 12 with PWA

Tags: ios, oauth, progressive-web-apps

For some reason I am unable to redirect to the Oauth LinkedIn page, by doing a redirect on iOS 12, however it works on Android and UWP

I tried doing the redirect on the backend and also on the `HTML` front end, none of those worked

```
private void LoginWithLinkedIn()
{
    string clientID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkedInClientID"].ToString();
    string url = string.Format("https://linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&state=fooobar&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social",
                               clientID, HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/pwa/linkedin.aspx"));
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Not sure why it does work on `Android` and Windows but on `iOS 12`, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser (Safari) or only after you 'Add to Home'?

> This has been fixed after changes were made to the W3C spec. I can confirm oauth works in PWAs for iOS 12.2. iOS 12.2 is still in beta right now and is the first version to fix this issue

Ref:

- [iOS 11.3 breaks OAuth flow in PWA (Add to home shortcut)](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/100407)

Also see:

- [Google as an Auth provider doesn't work on iOS saved to homescreen](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/77)
- [PWAs on iOS 12.2 beta: the good, the bad, and the “not sure yet if good”](https://medium.com/@firt/pwas-on-ios-12-2-beta-the-good-the-bad-and-the-not-sure-yet-if-good-a37b6fa6afbf)
- [Remove the manifest from iOS to allow OAuth redirect to works](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwacompat/issues/15)

Comment: In the safari browser works great, however from the iOS test flight package it doesn't as an iOS app